# How to set large, 3 minute, audio delay in video MPlayer?

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, mplayer

I have a video where sound lags about 3 minutes behind video. I tried both MPlayer and VLC to play it.

*MPlayer* refuses to start with error message:

> The delay option must be <= 100.000000: 180.

The command was:

```
mplayer -delay 180 video.mp4
```

*VLC* allows to specify audio delay but became mute and spam with runtime errors:

> Could not convert timestamp 243262192096

VLC was called with empty parameters and audio delay was adjusted with keyboard shortcut `k`. It shifts delay for 50ms. The process went normally, but when I was about 40 sec delay, sound suddenly disappear and stdout became filled with the error message.

So, how can such a video be played under Linux?

Comment: done. I've added details to the question

Answer (score 0):

Same case here. My audio delay is 14 sec. When I specify delay of more than 3250 ms in VLC player, it gets mute. I tried on another video and found that this value is different for different files, for this file audio muted after specifying nearly 15000 ms delay.

Can not figure out reason behind this.